# Looking for a thorough comparison of French and Spanish

Tags: grammar, reference-request, french, spanish

Either in English, Spanish or French.
I haven't found a comparative  grammar but I got pretty excited with this monograph:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Portuguese_and_Spanish

I'm particularly interested on verb usage, pronoun usage, cognates and loanwords.

Comment: Take a look at the talk page of that article... (in principle, take a look at the talk page of any Wikipedia article. If Bismark was alive today, he would have to update his famous sentence about laws and sausages to include Wikipedia articles.)